# GNU Prolog - searching a list of facts

Tags: prolog, rules

I must be having a brain fart or something, but i just can't seem to find a solution to this.

If you have a list facts such as:

```
%country(country, population, capital)
country(sweden, 8823, stockholm).
country(usa, 221000, washington).
country(france, 56000, paris).
country(denmark, 3400, copenhagen).

%city(city, country, population)
city(lund, sweden, 88).
city(new_york, usa, 5000).
city(paris, usa, 1).
city(copenhagen, denmark, 1200).
city(aarhus, denmark, 330).
city(odense, denmark, 120).
city(stockholm, sweden, 350).
city(washington, usa, 3400).
city(paris, france, 2000).
city(marseilles, france, 1000).
```

I want to find the second largest populated city, which in this case would be washington, usa with 3400 people. How would you be able to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you go about finding the largest city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly shorter version of @sharky's excellent answer:

```
second_largest_city(Second) :-
    setof(Size/City, Country^city(City,Country,Size), Cities),
    append(_, [_/Second, _], Cities).
```

`setof` combines `findall` and `sort`. We collect `Size/City` pairs so they are sorted on size automatically. The construct `X^Goal` introduces an existentially quantified variable `X` (like ∃*x* in first-order logic).

Comment: Slightly shorter version one-liner of the shorter version from larsmans: second_largest_city(Second):- setof(Size/City, Country^city(City,Country,Size), [_, _/Second|_]).

Comment: @gusbro: we want the penultimate member of `Cities`, not the second.

Comment: ouch, you are right. That would be second_largest_city(Second):- setof(RSize/City, Country^Size^(city(City,Country,Size), RSize is -Size), [_, _/Second|_]). Probably not worth doing it one-liner this time...

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, but I don't even consider something longer than 80 characters a oneliner ;)

Comment: @larsmans; I had considered `setof/3`, but had forgotten it sorted solutions using `sort/2` in generating a set! In any case, I like this solution better - not only is it more concise, it's more efficient (plus, I learnt something...) +1

Comment: Not sure why i didn't think of this. Its so obvious now :p

Comment: @Matt: I just realised that I've assumed cities have different sizes; hadn't seen that @sharky considers that.

Comment: @larsmans, yes i realized that, but i don't think it matters in this case. I am studying for a final exam and it's one of those that the teacher probably wanted us to use something like this. Basically because i've never used sort in prolog or even findall for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out for size:

```
second_largest_city(City) :-
    findall(Size, city(_, _, Size), Sizes),
    sort(Sizes, SortedSizes),
    append(_, [Size2, _], SortedSizes),
    city(City, _Country, Size2).
```

**Explanation:** The `findall/3` finds the sizes of all `city/3` facts, which are sorted into *ascending* order by `sort/2` with *duplicates removed*. The call to `append/3` pattern matches to partition the sorted list `SortedSizes` into two parts; a list of any size (`_`) and a remainder of length two (`[Size2, _]`) - this binds the variable `Size2` to the second-largest city size from `city/3` facts. Lastly, all cities with this size are located amongst `city/3` facts, and are bound on the output.

**Note:** This won't work properly in general if your built-in for `sort/2` *doesn't* remove duplicates, because this leaves open the possibility that `city/3` facts with more than one equal maximum will return the maximum (largest) only. This implementation using `append/3` to seek the second-last element of the sorted list of sizes also assumes `sort/2` sorted numbers into ascending order.

Also, lastly, note that this will fail outright if there are less than two `city/3` facts -- but this is probably fine, given that the predicate seeks the 'second largest' city, and strictly speaking there wouldn't be one unless there are indeed at least two cities in the DB with different sizes. If this is an issue, you can just write more clauses for `second_largest_city/1` to handle such a case.

Comment: sort/2 isn't in ISO Prolog, but it is in Edinburgh Prolog with the semantics you describe, which was the foundation for the ISO standard.  It would be weird for a Prolog that supports ISO to have a sort/2 builtin with any other semantics: I'll guess there isn't one.

Comment: @Charles: SWI, YAP and SICStus have `sort/2` with the intended semantics. +1 for this answer.